# Format the double precision value in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the value from `postgresql` with formating. The formatting is user option like they want comma separator or not and with decimal place is 2,3 or 4 like.

So now i wrote query like this.

```
 Select to_char(rate,'FM999.00') as BasicSaleRate from table1
```

Its return ans `220.00`. How to write the query with comma separator value like this `'#,0.00'`. That means the value more than thousands return with comma separator or not.

Am using `postgresql 9.3`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this reference http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html
to_char(rate,'FM999,999.00')