# Jasper not returning proper precision of double Postgres column

Tags: java, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a query which is creating array of double values returned.

```
 SELECT array_agg(price) rm FROM product;
```

When I am running this query in Postgres Shell I am getting output as expected,

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+----------------------
rm             | {79.33,49}
```

But when I am running the same in `Jasper Report` I am getting output as

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+----------------------
rm             | {79.3299999999,49}
```

Is it the issue of Postgres JDBC driver or something is missing my query?

Comment: Did you get this value `79.3299999999,49` at textField?

Comment: Yes and field type is String

Comment: Did you try Double?

Comment: No. Because I am converting array rm to string and appending converting it to md5 hash for digital signature purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format the double precision value in Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159448/format-the-double-precision-value-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Alex K cant see any relevance to that possible duplicate.

Comment: True. no relation with that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is setting the `extra_float_digits` PostgreSQL variable to 0 for the connection.

If you create the connection yourself, you can directly do `connection.createStatement().execute("set extra_float_digits to 0")`

If you use a connection pool, you can highjack that validation query to do `select set_config('extra_float_digits', '0', false)`

And if none of the above apply, you can do it directly in your query as in `select set_config('extra_float_digits', '0', false), array_agg(price) rm from product`

Comment: Okay. Will try and let you know result by tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Did work. Why do we need to set `set_config('extra_float_digits', '0', false)` ? something wrong in `JDBC Driver` ?

Comment: That's how the driver works, I could't say whether it's wrong or not.  See for instance https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSO.4.64.0905141441030.12930%40leary.csoft.net